# Finding size of deleted open file in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I'm aware of all the hoopla around deleted open files in Linux still hanging around and taking space on the file system.

What I'm after is to find the size of these deleted open files.

`sudo find /proc/[0-9]*/fd -ls | grep '(deleted)'` gives me the list but it results in information about the "virtual symbolic link" from the proc filesystem, not the deleted files.

Is there a way to get this information?

Comment: Does "stat - L path" work? Alternatively, the "lsof"  might give you the info you need.

Comment: -L flag is possible shortest answer. stat without it gives wrong result, "stat -L $file" is right. Also, stat function in node, python and golang show right size too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This prints the `/proc/[pid]/fd/[fd]` path, its symlink target, and the size of the actual file:

```
find /proc/[0-9]*/fd -lname '*(deleted)' \
    -printf '%p => %l\t' -exec stat -Lc '%s' {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

There may be smarter ways to do it ;-)

Comment: Yep. Looks like it does it. Thanks.

Comment: Same with size first to allow sort : find /proc/[0-9]*/fd -lname '*(deleted)' 2>/dev/null | perl -lne '($l = readlink) =~ s/ \(deleted\)$//; print -s, " $_ $l"'  | sort -g